# Como fazer o Radio Button aparecer checado se o banco de dados for atualizado Android Studiop

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, radiobutton

Estou fazendo um app com perguntas e respostas, tenho um radiogroup, um textview e 3 botões: confirmar, próxima e voltar.

Estou tentando fazer com que uma vez que a pergunta seja respondida, ao retornar naquela pergunta a resposta seja mostrada nas seleções do radiogroup.

Porém quando retorno a pergunta a condição não deixar selecionar uma resposta nova é aplicada, porém a de mostrar o radio button checado não.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.button_next:

            int_lei=Integer.parseInt(temp_lei);
            int_lei ++;
            temp_lei= String.valueOf(int_lei);

            AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "admin", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase BasedeDados = admin.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor consulta1 = BasedeDados.rawQuery("select * from Escriturario where Lei="+temp_lei, null);
            consulta1.moveToFirst();

            Pergunta.setText(consulta1.getString(1));
            rb1.setText(consulta1.getString(2));
            rb2.setText(consulta1.getString(3));
            rb3.setText(consulta1.getString(4));
            rb4.setText(consulta1.getString(5));
            rb5.setText(consulta1.getString(6));

            feito = consulta1.getInt(8);

            if(feito != 6){
                rg.check(feito);
                rb1.setClickable(false);
                rb2.setClickable(false);
                rb3.setClickable(false);
                rb4.setClickable(false);
                rb5.setClickable(false);
                bt3.setClickable(false);

            }
            else{
                rg.clearCheck();
                rb1.setClickable(true);
                rb2.setClickable(true);
                rb3.setClickable(true);
                rb4.setClickable(true);
                rb5.setClickable(true);
                bt3.setClickable(true);
                }

            break;

        case R.id.button_back:
            int_lei=Integer.parseInt(temp_lei);
            int_lei --;
            temp_lei= String.valueOf(int_lei);

            if(1 <= int_lei) {

                admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "admin", null, 1);
                BasedeDados = admin.getWritableDatabase();

                consulta1 = BasedeDados.rawQuery("select * from Escriturario where Lei=" + temp_lei, null);
                consulta1.moveToFirst();

                Pergunta.setText(consulta1.getString(1));
                rb1.setText(consulta1.getString(2));
                rb2.setText(consulta1.getString(3));
                rb3.setText(consulta1.getString(4));
                rb4.setText(consulta1.getString(5));
                rb5.setText(consulta1.getString(6));
                feito = consulta1.getInt(8);

                if(feito != 6){
                    rg.check(feito);
                    rb1.setClickable(false);
                    rb2.setClickable(false);
                    rb3.setClickable(false);
                    rb4.setClickable(false);
                    rb5.setClickable(false);
                    bt3.setClickable(false);

                }
                else{
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    rb1.setClickable(true);
                    rb2.setClickable(true);
                    rb3.setClickable(true);
                    rb4.setClickable(true);
                    rb5.setClickable(true);
                    bt3.setClickable(true);
                }               
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button_validate:

            admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper
                        (this, "admin", null, 1);
            BasedeDados = admin.getWritableDatabase();
            consulta1 = BasedeDados.rawQuery("select * from Escriturario where Lei=" + temp_lei, null);
            consulta1.moveToPosition(int_lei);
            resposta = consulta1.getInt(7);
            int int_resposta = -1;

            switch(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
            case R.id.rb1:
                int_resposta = 1;
                break;

            case R.id.rb2:
                int_resposta = 2;
                break;

            case R.id.rb3:
                int_resposta = 3;
                break;

            case R.id.rb4:
                int_resposta = 4;
                break;

            case R.id.rb5:
                int_resposta = 5;
                break;
            }
                    ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
                    registro.put("feito", int_resposta);
                    BasedeDados.update("Escriturario", registro, "Lei =" + temp_lei, null);

                    if (resposta == int_resposta) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Resposta correta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    if (resposta != int_resposta) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Resposta incorreta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Selecione uma resposta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    rb1.setClickable(false);
                    rb2.setClickable(false);
                    rb3.setClickable(false);
                    rb4.setClickable(false);
                    rb5.setClickable(false);
                    bt3.setClickable(false);              
    }
```

Poderiam me ajudar a chegar no comportamento esperado.